# PHP ftp_connect() doesn't work and returns false

Tags: php, ftp

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $ftpServer = 'ftp://123.website.com';
    $ftpUsername = 'username';
    $ftpPassword = 'password';
    $remotePath = $_POST['remotePath'];

    $fileToUpload = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $fileExtension = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];
    $fileName = $_POST['file_name'] . '.' . $fileExtension;
    
    $conn = ftp_connect($ftpServer, 80);
    if ($conn) {
        $login = ftp_login($conn, $ftpUsername, $ftpPassword);
        if ($login) {
            if (ftp_put($conn, $remotePath . $fileName, $fileToUpload, FTP_BINARY)) {
                echo "<p>File upload succesfull</p>";
            } else {
                echo "<p>Error when uploading file</p>";
            }
            ftp_close($conn);
        } else {
            echo "<p>FTP-Login failed</p>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<p>Couldnt connect to FTP server</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

I get

> Couldnt connect to FTP server

The port is 80. I can open the FTP server with the correct log-in details. What can it be that I can't connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

The `hostname` parameter of [`ftp_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php) takes a *hostname* (or an IP address), not a URL.

So it should  be:

```
$ftpServer = '123.website.com';
...
$conn = ftp_connect($ftpServer, 80);
```